# Vim mapping for diffget | diffput not working with v:count

Tags: vim, merge, count, diff, shortcut

Pretty new to mappings in Vim,

In Diff Mode I've got `C-Up` and `C-Down` mapped to `[c` and `]c` for diffjumping. I'm wanting to map `C-Right` and `C-Left` to `:<C-U>diffput v:count<CR>` and `:<C-U>diffget v:count<CR>` respectively to speed up merging.

```
nnoremap <C-Left> :<C-U>diffget v:count<CR>
nnoremap <C-Right> :<C-U>diffput v:count<CR>
nnoremap <C-Up> [c
nnoremap <C-Down> ]c
```

This should.... put from buffer # or get from buffer #.

But I get the error "no matching buffer for v:count".

the command looks to be taking v:count literally and running `:diffget v:count` instead of `:diffget 3` for example.. how do I get v:count to resolve to a number? like dereference the variable?

I can `echo "diffget v:count"` and that looks to be correct... but obviously doesn't do anything...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Note that a specialized [vi.SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) sub-site exists. You *might* get faster / better answers there for your Vim questions.

Comment: You want us to help you fix your mappings but you are not showing them. Also, what's the point when you already have `:help do` and `:help dp`?

Comment: @romainl ive added them. I supposed i dont understand how to map ```[count]<C-Left> to [count]do``` and have it work the same.. you sound knowledgeable how would i make them work the same?

Comment: I wouldn't map anything. I would use `do` and `dp` which are built-in and do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in vi.SE

`<expr> <C-Left> ":\<C-U>diffget " .. v:count .. "\<CR>"`